# How to automate download Google signed universal APK to distribute outside Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane, huawei-developers, android-app-signing

I have app using Play App Signing. I want upload app to Huawei App Gallery. Google recommend to download signed, universal APK from bundle explorer and then upload to store outside Google Play.

> If you also distribute your app outside of Google Play or plan to
> later and want to use the same signing key, you have two options:
>
> - Either let Google generate the key (recommended) and then download a
>   signed, universal APK from the app bundle explorer to distribute
>   outside of Google Play. You can also download signed APKs from the
>   Google Play Developer API.
> - Or you can generate the app signing key
>   you want to use for every app store, and then transfer a copy of it to
>   Google when you opt in to Play App Signing.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en

How I can automate this with Fastlane so I not need to manually download universal APK from bundle explorer every time?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest generating your own script using Google Play Store Developer API

This is the reference page
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/download-apks

You can follow this page to learn how you can generate the token for your download script
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started

Generating tokens might be a little tricky if you are not familiar with the process, but the rest of the process is easy,

1. Generate Bearer access token
2. Use the token and your package name to generate Edit ID
3. Use the Edit ID to upload your Bundle and Deobfuscation files
4. Update your edit
5. Commit your edit
6. Get the list of available signed APKs
7. Download your signed APK

Remember, you have to upload a bundle because there is no signed APK API if you upload an APK in step 3.
Also, it is better when updating your edit to use the draft status in step 5, it enables you to test the signed APK before release.
You can find the detail of all API in the link I have shared

Answer (score 0):

Using python you can do this:

```
import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument('package_name',
                       help='The package name. Example: com.android.sample')
argparser.add_argument('key_file',
                       nargs='?',
                       default='key.p12',
                       help='The path to the p12 key file.')
argparser.add_argument('account_email',
                       nargs='?',
                       default='...',
                       help='service account email.')

def main():
  flags = argparser.parse_args()

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
      flags.account_email,
      flags.key_file,
      scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'])
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  service = build('androidpublisher', 'v3', http=http)

  package_name = flags.package_name

  try:

    edit_request = service.edits().insert(body={}, packageName=package_name)
    result = edit_request.execute()
    edit_id = result['id']

    apks_result = service.edits().apks().list(editId=edit_id, packageName=package_name).execute()

    #https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/androidpublisher_v3.html
    generatedApks = service.generatedapks().list(packageName=package_name, versionCode= '200000').execute()
    downloadId = generatedApks['generatedApks'][0]['generatedUniversalApk']['downloadId']
    #pass versionCode
    apkFile_media = service.generatedapks().download_media(packageName=package_name, versionCode= '200000', downloadId=downloadId).execute()

    #put version on file name
    file = open('app.apk', 'wb')
    file.write(apkFile_media)
    file.close()
```

[documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/androidpublisher_v3.html)